# Opening a Windows Explorer from C++ does not inherit environment

Tags: c++

I'm trying to open a Windows Explorer from C++ code and inherit the environment of my application. While this perfectly works for a command prompt (or other executables), opening a Windows Explorer does not inherit the parent environment.

```
// Opens a cmd and inherits
ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), _T("cmd"), "", NULL, SW_SHOW);

// Opens an explorer but does not inherit
ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), _T("explorer"), "", NULL, SW_SHOW);
```

Also, trying to open an explorer with `system` or `CreateProcess` does not inherit anything.

```
system("explorer C:\\");

CreateProcess("C:\\Windows\\Explorer.exe",       
      " C:\\",                
      NULL,
      NULL,
      FALSE,
      CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      &StartupInfo,
      &ProcessInfo);
```

For `CreateProcess`, the [Microsoft manuals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) are very clear, when the `lpEnvironment`(7th) parameter is set to NULL, the new process uses the environment of the calling process.

> lpEnvironment [in, optional]
> A pointer to the environment block for the new process. If this parameter is NULL, the new process uses the environment of the calling process.

Why is this not happening when opening a Windows Explorer?

Comment: What proof do you have that the environment is not inherited?

Comment: Opening a windows explorer, then launching  `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` and running `env` reveals missing environment variables.

Comment: Maybe Windows Explorer intentionally ignores any environment it is passed?  Or it creates a new environment from all the system settings when it creates a new process, so it isn't passing its environment to child processes?

Comment: Usually explorer windows share the same process, and the proces is usually already running as desktop. When you run `explorer.exe` usually it just signal the existing process to launch a new window and then finishes, and your environment variables with it. I recall there was an option to disable that, but I don't know if it would help.